# What is the required lifetime of struct kevent passed into kevent changelist?

Tags: macos, bsd, kqueue

The signature of the `kevent` system call for OSX and BSD is as follows:

```
     int
     kevent(int kq, const struct kevent *changelist, int nchanges, struct kevent *eventlist,
         int nevents, const struct timespec *timeout);
```

Suppose I have an invocation like the following:

```
  struct kevent kqueue_event;
  EV_SET(&kqueue_event, fd_to_add, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD, 0, /*data=*/0, NULL);

  kevent(watcher_fd, &kqueue_event, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

If the above invocation is inside a function, the `kqueue_event` structure will go out of scope as soon as the function returns.

Given that I just passed a pointer to this structure into the `kevent` function, is this going to cause problems for me down the road, or is the structure no longer needed after `kevent` returns?

The [man page](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) does not appear to say anything about how long the array needs to stick around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can forget and don't care about the changelist passed after the successful kevent() call.

Take a look here https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/bsd/kern/kern_event.c at kevent_internal function.

What they do there, they call kevent_modern_copyin (or legacy_copyin), both with copyin inside, so this structure is copied into kernel memory, and lives there now.